# What effects do the enchantments "Lure" and "Luck of the Sea" have?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What are the effects of the **Lure** and **Luck of the Sea** fishing pole enchantments, and how much does each higher level of the enchantments improve the effect?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the MC Wiki https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Enchantments

***Luck of the Sea:***

```
Decreases odds of catching worthless junk
```

Lowers chance of "junk" catches by 2.5% per level and increases chance of "treasure" catches by 1% per level.

**[In 1.9:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#History)** Lowers chance of Junk and Increases chance of treasure by 2% per level. Reduces chance of fish by 0.15% per level.

***Lure***

```
Increases rate of fish biting your hook
```

Decreases time before fish bite your hook by 5 seconds per level. Also decreases chances of both "junk" and "treasure" catches by 1% per level.

**[In 1.9:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#History)** no longer affects loot tables. There is no change in junk and treasure chances.

Comment: Just a note here, I looked around a bit for the wait time and catch chances without enchants: a random wait time of 5-45 seconds (some conditions change this, read the wiki page for more info), a 10% change of catching "junk", and a 5% chance of catching "treasure" [MC Wiki page for Fishing Poles](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Fishing_Rod)

Comment: Hello, this is from the future, minecraft 1.9 made fishing awesome. Lure no longer reduces chance of treasure. I'm editting the answer to reflect it.

Answer (score -1):

**easy version**

- luck of sea: lowers chance of junk
- lure: makes fish bite more often

Answer (score -2):

On a fishing pole the lure enchantment book makes it easier to get fish.

On a fishing pole the luck of the sea enchantment book decreases the % of getting stupid junk like name tags and saddles.

Comment: Your answer repeats previous answers.  That is why it's getting down voted.

Comment: Both name tags and saddles are considered "treasure" by the luck of the sea enchantment, so you would actually get more of those particular items. http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Fishing_Rod

Comment: I donw voted because there's already an answer. If there's more info that wasn'r on the answer, edit it or explain yourself in your answer.